# Unable to access GZipStrean due to protection level

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I just want to access System.IO.Compression.GZipStream class to decompress Web Http response. But I am unable to access GZipStream class due to protection level. I am using Mvvm cross for mobile development.

- Here is GZipStream class code :

  namespace System.IO.Compression

{

```
internal class GZipStream : Stream

{
    public GZipStream(Stream stream, CompressionMode mode);
    public GZipStream(Stream stream, CompressionMode mode, bool leaveOpen);
```

}
}

- I need to access first constructor to create instance of GZipStream.
- So is there any other way to create GZipStream type instance ?

Comment: What does it mean, you cannot access public constructor of GzipStream? May you can provide more details about your issue?

Comment: Yes @Max, i want to use public constructor of GZipStream  class

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Forms for PCL I resolve this problem just replaced **TargetFrameworkProfile** in your_project_name **.csproj**

FROM:

> Profile259

TO:

> Profile111

Also possible to try install NuGet package **Microsoft.Bcl.Compression**, this option although resolve problem with access to GZipStream, but in time compilation I had System.TypeLoadException.

Comment: Can I know what Profile111 means?How is it different from Profile259? Any impact?

Comment: Profile111 compatible with the .NET Standard 1.1 and PCL: .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1

Profile259 - .NET Standard 1.0 and PCL: .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8
 
There is more: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compress byte[] buffer array like this

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                gzip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                gzip.Close();
            }

            compressed = ms.ToArray();
        }
```